# Convert MySQL syntax to PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, variables, mariadb

I use this code in MySQL to order by 'anotherColumn' and then get the row number of 'myColumn' and then I perform a calculation and set 'myColumn' to the result:

`SET @c = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable);  SET @rownum = 0; UPDATE myTable SET myColumn = @c * (@rownum:= 1 + @rownum) ORDER BY anotherColumn DESC LIMIT 100000;`

I'm trying to achieve the same thing in Postgresql but am getting a lot of errors. I have:

`SET c = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable);  SET rownum = 0; UPDATE myTable SET myColumn = c * (rownum:= 1 + rownum) ORDER BY anotherColumn DESC LIMIT 100000;`

.. but it gives me an error at the first parenthesis. If I remove those parenthesis like this:

`SET c = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable;  SET rownum = 0; UPDATE myTable SET myColumn = c * (rownum:= 1 + rownum) ORDER BY anotherColumn DESC LIMIT 100000;`

.. then it gives me an error at the SELECT. If I just set c to equal 0, I get an error way down at the ORDER. Does anyone know how to convert my code from MySQL to PostgreSQL?

Comment: Please add before and after sample data to your question.  Most likely, you just want `ROW_NUMBER` here.

Comment: how do i insert a table?

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: One column ('anotherColumn') has some values in it. I want to order the table by that column. Then I want the values in the column next to it ('myColumn') to be calculated based on the total number of rows and the row number of that particular cell.

Comment: I just created it using the GUI. It's literally two columns. One has some random values in it and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This "pattern" in MySQL is typically used to work around the absence of window function.

You don't need variables in Postgres to achieve something like that:

```
update my_table
  set my_column = t.cnt + t.rn
from (
  select pk_column, 
         (select count(*) from my_table) as cnt,
         row_number() over (order by another_column) as rn
  from my_table
  limit 100000
) t
where t.pk_column = my_table.pk_column;
```

Where `pk_column` is the primary key column of your table. If you have more than one PK column, you need to use all of them.

Comment: It's so close to working. The calculation of `t.cnt + t.rn` is actually `100/t.cnt * t.rn`. So one result should be 16.67 = 17 but the column value is 16. I've tried replacing it with `ROUND((100/t.cnt) * t.rn)` but it doesn't seem to make any difference. It seems to automatically cut off the decimals before I have a chance to round.

Comment: @Normajean: Postgres uses integer division for integers. If you want decimal values, you need to cast it, e.g. `100 / t.cnt::numeric + t.rn`

Comment: It's rounding the `100/t.cnt`. Is there a way to make it stop rounding this before the multiplication?

Comment: @Normajean: No, it doesn't round, it's just using integers like a_horse_with_no_name already said. An integer divided by another integer results in an integer. An integer divided by a numeric will result in a numeric result. That means you have to cast one of the columns to the datatype you want. a_horse_with_no_name already gave you an example.